# Codenameone - Null Pointer Exception on Android when button is clicked

Tags: codenameone

I see following error log from crash reports on google play.This is happening on the click of a button.I don't know what is triggering this issue. Please let me know if any one face similar issue.  Thanks

Comment: This looks like a bug in our implementation, we're looking into it

Comment: is there a ETA for this implementation? Please advise.

Comment: How could I verify when this fix is applied on the build server? is there an issue created in the tracker?

Comment: Here's [the PR](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/1079726ae967185f1b85d223a740f7b7ec387a39) where they addressed the NPE.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the implementation, a fix was committed and would be available in the update next Friday (October 26th 2018).

Comment: @Shai..Can I assume this fix has been committed already and I can give the build now. Please advise. Thanks